# Gmap js API draw route between places and use priority order

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i'm using this gmap waypoints approach to draw route between start and end places(or it can be coordinates) on google map

```
var DIRECTIONS_SERVICE = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var DIRECTIONS_RENDER = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: TOUR_GMAP});

DIRECTIONS_SERVICE.route({
    origin: { 'placeId': startPoint },
    destination: { 'placeId': endPoint },
    waypoints: waypoints,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
}, function(response, status) {

    if (status === 'OK') {          
        //DIRECTIONS_RENDER.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } ); // hides AB, B .. points
        DIRECTIONS_RENDER.setDirections(response);
        DIRECTIONS_RENDER_RESPONSE = response;          
        TM_calculateRouteDistance(START_TIME);
    } else {
        window.alert('Problem in showing direction due to ' + status);
    }
});
```

**The question** i know that google draws optimal route, but i need to add some priority e.g. i need exactly point C to be as first visit point after start point (so it would be converted to point A).

Is there such porioitying option in DirectionsRenderer ?
Or is there another aproxach that i will give exactly e.g. 5 points ang google will drow route by exact given order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `optimizeWaypoints: true` from your request, then put the waypoints in the order you want.

```
DIRECTIONS_SERVICE.route({
    origin: { 'placeId': startPoint },
    destination: { 'placeId': endPoint },
    waypoints: waypoints,
    // optimizeWaypoints: true, <=========== remove this
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
},
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nxLz9kds/)

with `optimizeWaypoints: true`:
[image: resulting map with optimizeWaypoints: true]

without `optimizeWaypoints: true`:
[image: resulting map without optimizeWaypoints: true]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var startPoint = "ChIJHQ6aMnBTwokRc-T-3CrcvOE"; // Newark, NJ
  var endPoint = "ChIJGzE9DS1l44kRoOhiASS_fHg"; // Boston, MA
  var waypoints = [{
      location: {
        placeId: "ChIJS_tPzDQK3okRxCjnoBJjoeE"
      }, // Albany, NY
      stopover: true
    },
    {
      location: {
        placeId: "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g"
      }, // New York, NY
      stopover: true
    },
    {
      location: {
        placeId: "ChIJpVER8hFT5okRmVl96ahKjsw"
      }, // Hartford, CT
      stopover: true
    }
  ]
  var TOUR_GMAP = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  var DIRECTIONS_SERVICE = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var DIRECTIONS_RENDER = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: TOUR_GMAP
  });

  DIRECTIONS_SERVICE.route({
    origin: {
      'placeId': startPoint
    },
    destination: {
      'placeId': endPoint
    },
    waypoints: waypoints,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {

    if (status === 'OK') {
      //DIRECTIONS_RENDER.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } ); // hides AB, B .. points
      DIRECTIONS_RENDER.setDirections(response);
      DIRECTIONS_RENDER_RESPONSE = response;
      TM_calculateRouteDistance(START_TIME);
    } else {
      window.alert('Problem in showing direction due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```